# Openstack multiple nodes: separate Glance and Keystone machines

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openstack, openstack-keystone, openstack-glance

I followed the guide on [hastexo](http://www.hastexo.com/resources/docs/installing-openstack-essex-20121-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin) to create an OpenStack Cloud. The Keystone service and the are supposed to run on separate machines. However, when I wanted to run 
glance-api in the console for debugging I had the following error:

> ERROR: Unable to load glance-api-keystone from configuration file /etc/glance/glance-api-paste.ini.
>   Got: ImportError('No module named keystone.middleware.auth_token',)

So the Glance API isn't running. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Openstack Essex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use keystone for auth, you will need to install some extra python modules. These are needed for both the keystone server and its clients.
Try running

```
 apt-get install python-keystone python-keystoneclient
```